# Live scraping real time data from webpage?

Tags: web-scraping

I am currently scraping a website to get data which refreshes at random intervals, using Selenium. I am scraping all the elements of the webpage in a loop - which is obviously overkill if the data hasnt changed.

Is there a way to "monitor" a webpage for changes in certain elements, and then scrape the data when it changes?